# PHP Infinite Sleep

Tags: php, resources, sleep, infinite

My web page has the following sleep line in it:

```
sleep(600);
```

For the user, it will appear as if the page is loading "forever". This effect is desired.

However, this will create a process that lasts for 10 minutes, eating up system resources. Is there a way to create the same effect for a user (loading "forever") without having a lengthy process?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: In a web world where developers strive for speed and best user experience, you want to have someone hanging there for 10 minutes on your loading page?

Comment: throw a spinner on the page :) http://www.ajaxload.info/

Comment: Yes. By the way, the request is being made from a C# app. So any client-sided scripting won't be a solution.

Comment: Why don't you just send a header redirect to the script to some other site or a 404 URL not found?

Comment: Sounds good. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a jQuery script.  Is that something that would work, because it is a design reason right?  Or am I thinking wrong.

```
body {display: none}
```

Then for some jquery

```
$("body").delay(MILLISECOND_WAIT).attr("display", "block");
```

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping something more server sided rather than the browser.

Comment: how can you use jQuery to do it? This answer could be made better.

Comment: Well not do exactly how it is in PHP, but give the same effect of slow loading.  Like I said, I am assuming it is a design reason, because I cannot think of any other reason why anyone would intentionally do such a thing.  Even if it is waiting for data, you can still have jQuery delay the response.